# Azure devops server hangs on send work items in email

Tags: azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

we have recent upgraded from TFS to Azure Devops server 2020.01.

Now we encounter an issue that when we want to mail work items it stays on 'please wait'.
Occasionally it works, but largely not.
Already tried with different browsers.

Within chrome we do see this error message:

> Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async-vlBqqqCimG3tKYci5_YvSYAaTiC55_my7aZvW0q0W6eo=:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'guid' of undefined
>     at t.sendMessage (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async-vlBqqqCimG3tKYci5_YvSYAaTiC55_my7aZvW0q0W6eo=:17)
>     at Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async-vlBqqqCimG3tKYci5_YvSYAaTiC55_my7aZvW0q0W6eo=:15
>     at n. (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vG0KUJjg3--UYqBo9qQKb4H_-6CYjE75N8kARpETg7Vg=:179)
>     at n._func (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vG0KUJjg3--UYqBo9qQKb4H_-6CYjE75N8kARpETg7Vg=:77)
>     at n._invoke (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vG0KUJjg3--UYqBo9qQKb4H_-6CYjE75N8kARpETg7Vg=:77)
>     at Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vG0KUJjg3--UYqBo9qQKb4H_-6CYjE75N8kARpETg7Vg=:77

Does anyone else have experience with this?

Comment: If your upgradation meets this [Supported upgrade paths](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020#supported-upgrade-paths), and there are not errors during this upgradation, I suggest that you [re-configure an SMTP server and customize email for alerts and feedback requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-customize-alerts?view=azure-devops-2020), after it is done, restart your Azure DevOps Server to check the result. Also contact IT to check if there is proxy or firewall blocks the email notification.

Comment: Hi Allemanie, How about this issue? Do you follow wallezzi's troubleshooting steps to check the result?

Comment: Hi, we followed the upgrade path as mentioned. SMTP normally works where mails are sent with other functionality and it does not result in an issue for some work items.

Comment: You could try to use other popular browsers to check the result.

Comment: Having the same issue after upgrade from 2020 to 2020.1.  The issue only happen when you trying to send from a list. if you enter the workitem and send it from there it works fine. We have it also in our test server which we rebooted\deleted the mail settings but nothing happen.